# Web Audio API - Playing synchronized sounds

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to find out what the best way to play synchronised Audio tracks through the Web Audio API is. What i'm trying to achieve is to play multiple .wav files at once with as little delay in synchronisation of the audio tracks as possible.

The only way i've found to play multiple audio tracks at the same time is to create multiple audio tracks and loop through them in a for loop. The issue with this is that there's a tiny amount of delay between the loops. The delay is only a couple of milliseconds usually depending on the users machine however when I have something like 30 audio tracks that need to start at the same time and my loop has to loop over 30 tracks and call `source.start()` on each of them, there is a noticeable delay by the time the loop starts the 30th track.

As I need the tracks to play as on time as possible, I was wondering if there was perhaps another solution. Maybe for example where via the Web Audio API you could load in multiple sources and then have a native global event that would start all those tracks simultaneously.

Here is some code that shows the issue:

```
const audioBuffer1 = '...'; // Some decoded audio buffer
const audioBuffer2 = '...'; // some other decoded audio buffer
const audioBuffer3 = '...'; // and another audio buffer

const arrayOfAudioBuffers = [audioBuffer1, audioBuffer2, audioBuffer3];    
const context = new AudioContext();

function play(audioBuffer) {
  const source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audioBuffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start();
}

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfAudioBuffers.length; i++) {
  // every time this loops the play function is 
  // called around 2 milliseconds after the previous
  // one causing sounds to get slightly out of sync
  play(arrayOfAudioBuffers[i]);
}
```

An example of an app that uses multiple track sources and manages to keep good synchronisation is [Splice Beatmaker](https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker). I've explored a few libraries such as Howler and Tone but they appear to use the loop approach I believe.

Would love to hear any suggestions as to how to tackle this issue

Comment: _"I need to play multiple audio tracks at the same time"_ Think like an audio engineer. You need to **mix your audio samples**. What would they do? For example back in a time of cassettes, they did not press "play" on _X_-num of tape decks (with delay being relative to hand speed). Simplify that process to playing one cassette (or `audioBuffer`) that holds all sounds.

Comment: Is it possible to link multiple sounds to one audioBuffer though? This was the preferred route however I did not find a way to link multiple sounds together...

Comment: hey pal, I found this. Maybe it can bring you new ideas :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1bRi4El0iw

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Due to browsers protecting against fingerprinting and timing attacks, **timing precision under the hood can be reduced or rounded by modern browsers**. 
This would mean `source.start(offset)` could never be 100% accurate or reliable in your case. 
What I recommend is **mixing down** the sources byte by byte then playing back the final mix. 
Assuming all audio sources should start at the same time, and time till load is flexible the following will work:

**Example:**

```
const audioBuffer1 = '...'; // Some decoded audio buffer
const audioBuffer2 = '...'; // some other decoded audio buffer
const audioBuffer3 = '...'; // and another audio buffer

const arrayOfAudioBuffers = [audioBuffer1, audioBuffer2, audioBuffer3];
```

We'll need to calculate the length of the entire song by obtaining the buffer with the maximum length.

```
let songLength = 0;

for(let track of arrayOfAudioBuffers){
    if(track.length > songLength){
        songLength = track.length;
    }
}
```

Next i've created a method that will take in `arrayOfAudioBuffers` and output a
final mixdown.

```
function mixDown(bufferList, totalLength, numberOfChannels = 2){

    //create a buffer using the totalLength and sampleRate of the first buffer node
    let finalMix = context.createBuffer(numberOfChannels, totalLength, bufferList[0].sampleRate);

    //first loop for buffer list
    for(let i = 0; i < bufferList.length; i++){

           // second loop for each channel ie. left and right   
           for(let channel = 0; channel < numberOfChannels; channel++){

            //here we get a reference to the final mix buffer data
            let buffer = finalMix.getChannelData(channel);

                //last is loop for updating/summing the track buffer with the final mix buffer 
                for(let j = 0; j < bufferList[i].length; j++){
                    buffer[j] += bufferList[i].getChannelData(channel)[j];
                }

           }
    }

    return finalMix;
}
```

*fyi: you can always remove one loop by hard coding the update per each channel.*

Now we can use our `mixDown` function like so:

```
const mix = context.createBufferSource();
//call our function here
mix.buffer = mixDown(arrayOfAudioBuffers, songLength, 2);

mix.connect(context.destination);

//will playback the entire mixdown
mix.start()
```

More about web audio precision timing [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/currentTime#Reduced_time_precision)

Note:
    We could use `OfflineAudioContext` to accomplish the same thing but precision is not guaranteed and
    still relies on looping and calling `start()` on each individual source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just want to point out that the comment about timing accuracy of `source.start(offset)` is not quite right.  If the offset is far enough in the future (maybe 10 ms or more), the it will start at the time specified, modulo the sample rate of the context.  Clock precision is not reduced.

Comment: Precision is reduced by 2ms as stated here in the docs: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/currentTime#Reduced_time_precision

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that.  Is it just that the reported value is rounded to 2 ms?  If not, then I don't know how anyone can do precise scheduling of audio with Firefox, which defeats the sample-accurate timing expected for WebAudio.

Comment: I asked a Firefox WebAudio dev.  He said the reporting is rounded.  But if you schedule things in the future all at the same time, they will be synchronized, but perhaps are 1 ms off from the actual time.

Comment: How to make an offset in milliseconds in the code above? I don't see any offsets

Comment: The reason there's no offsets in the solution above is because NO OFFSETS ARE NEEDED. All tracks are MIXED DOWN first, which means all the tracks (BUFFERS) are merged byte by byte into one array. Then that one array is played back  as ONE PIECE OF AUDIO. A use case for offset is if MULTIPLE sounds need to be scheduled for playback...but in this case the multiple sounds are merge before hand into a SINGLE sound.

Answer (score 4):

You could try applying an offset:

```
function play(audioBuffer, startTime) {
  const source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audioBuffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start(startTime);
}

const startTime = context.currentTime + 1.0; // one second in the future

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfAudioBuffers.length; i++) {
  play(arrayOfAudioBuffers[i], startTime);
}
```

This code will queue up all sounds to play at the same time, one second in the future. If this works, you can tune down the delay to make the sounds play more immediately, or even calculate the right delay based on the number of tracks (e.g. 2 ms per track * 30 tracks = 60 ms delay)

Comment: delaying it is a viable option, the issue here is the delay won't always be 2ms, it will depend on the users machine. Will give it an upvote anyway

Answer (score 2):

You never just `source.start();` (start means right now) instead you `source.start(sometimeinthefuture);` web-audio has its own internal clock and is very precise. and make sure all those tracks you have in that loop have the same *sometimeinthefuture*.

Also you don't need to mix down a final mix like the answer indicates, you just need to create a scheduling system. Where you schedule via javascript's timeout or setinterval into the future on the web-audio clock.

This is explained in the article a [tale of two clocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/). There's also [a simpler article](https://sonoport.github.io/web-audio-clock.html) that explains this. Also check out [Looper.js](https://github.com/lautr3k/Looper.js) that uses this scheduling system concept to sync an audio looper (where multiple tracks need to be synchronized).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to run all these process like in a parallel mode in order to have zero delay or latency.

The problem is that javascript, unlike java, has a event loop that only can manage a single thread (although it has newer function that are designed to run promises and async-like functions).

- I have done some little research and found This:
  [Parallel.js
  Easy multi-core processing with javascript](https://parallel.js.org/).

As they say:

> Parallel.js solves that problem by giving you high level access to multi-core processing using web workers. It runs on node and in your browser.

Normally the web-browser use only one web-worker per open tab, but there are some libraries that extend this functions so you can run multiple threads and run parallel process in your web app.
I have never tried, but here are some articles so you can start your research:

- [Mozilla.org - 
  The Path to Parallel JavaScript](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2015/02/26/the-path-to-parallel-javascript/)
- [Itnext.io - Parallel programming in JavaScript using Web Workers](https://itnext.io/achieving-parallelism-in-javascript-using-web-workers-8f921f2d26db)
- [JonResig.com - Computing with JavaScript Web Workers](https://johnresig.com/blog/web-workers/)

Im a very newbie programmer and maybe this answer isnt very good, but I hope it was helpful.
Sorry about my english :)